# Calibrate multimeter VC9205A

Tags: multimeter

I have a multimeter type VC9205S.  I plugged it in to power 9 volts because the battery is empty.

Hours later, negative readout values ​​began to appear.

1- Can the device be calibrated or not repairable?

[image]

2- I measured the cut-off transformer input voltage for a power circuit and had a cut-off frequency of 160 kHz and voltage 300 volts so is that the cause

Comment: What do you messure? Open circuit? Short circuit? I can’t tell from the picture.

Comment: what device are you talking about?

Comment: You're on the 200 Ohm range when you say you're measuring a fairly dead battery. That won't work (as the battery recovers unloaded it'll generate some voltage, preventing correct ohms readings) but doesn't indicate anything wrong with the multimeter.

Comment: when i measure resistor or volts or...etc,then the device added minuse value so the result is error

Comment: If your "plugged it in to power 9 volts" power supply galvanically coupled with your measurement circuit, then the multimeter will possibly not work. Please show us the whole picture and provide schematics and more photos. BTW usually the black measuring cable should be connected to COM and the red one to V/Ω. Do you measure a resistor or a cable which is not under any voltage/current? Try to use a 9V block battery - no external supply.

Comment: thanks 2 all...i will try

Comment: I used a 9 volt battery and it remained the same problem

Comment: It measures resistance by (softly) forcing a small current through the device and measuring the voltage. If you connect it to a voltage source, it will get confused. It has negative voltage across it's terminals when it tries to send a positive current. So you see a negative resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: Based on the new comment, it seems the multimeter is faulty.
**The type of incorrect display shown cannot be fixed by calibration.**

---

Original:

> Can the device be calibrated or not repairable?

If you are starting to read negative resistance values on your multimeter, then either:

- the multimeter is faulty; or
- you are misusing it (e.g. by injecting a voltage across the meter terminals, while trying to measure resistance); or
- the replacement 9 V power source you are using, in place of the multimeter's battery, is unsuitable (e.g. excessive ripple or RF component on the 9 V output) and that is causing the meter to (temporarily?) malfunction.

One thing that will **not** resolve malfunctions like that, is calibration.

Your question seems to imply that the multimeter was OK until the battery was empty and you used a different 9 V source. If that is true, then you should consider the possibility that the 9 V source is the cause of the multimeter's malfunctions. It would help if you added more details about that power source to the question, and added some photos of how you connected it.

Try to get another suitable 9 V battery (even if you can only borrow one for 5 minutes) and re-test the multimeter operation using that.

---

Update:

> I used a 9 volt battery and it remained the same problem

Thanks for that new information.

Therefore your problem is one of the *other* remaining options which I listed above. Either:

- the multimeter is faulty; or
- you are misusing it (e.g. by injecting a voltage across the meter terminals, while trying to measure resistance)

It *seems* that the multimeter is faulty, if there is just a simple resistor hiding in the white tape in [your photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzKwN.jpg), since the multimeter is displaying a negative (though unclear) value.

Depending on how much time you want to spend on this problem, you could edit the question to give *exact* details about the sequence of events explaining exactly how you used the multimeter, starting from when it was working normally through to when it first started to behave abnormally. There *might* be a clue in there about an event which caused the problem - but perhaps there won't be any clues in that list of events, and the reason will remain unknown.

---

Update:

> I measured the cut-off transformer input voltage for a power circuit and had a cut-off frequency of 160 kHz and voltage 300 volts so is that the cause

I see that you have just added that new information to the question.

I don't fully understand that short description. However if this was the only measurement you did between the multimeter working correctly, and it then starting to show erroneous readings, it's likely something about measuring that (high-energy?) source did damage the meter.

Comment: i am used 9 v source by regulator 7809.........the error is same and not solved...

Comment: @engZuhair - So how do you know that the 9 V output from that is suitable for the multimeter (hint: you cannot know that!). Did you use an oscilloscope to check the output from your 7809 circuit for unexpected ripple and oscillations? I have answered your question about calibration - that will not be the solution to your problem. **Am I correct in understanding that your problem only started when you used the 9 V external supply?** As I stated above: "*Try to get another suitable 9 V battery (even if you can only borrow one for 5 minutes) and re-test the multimeter operation using that.*"

Comment: thx....i will try

Comment: I used a 9 volt battery and it remained the same problem

Comment: @engZuhair - Thanks for that new information. I have edited my answer to add some further analysis.

Comment: i will try to solve it..........thx 2 all

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the multimeter was damaged by either reverse connection of the 9V source or a sneak path from a voltage you measured through your external power supply to ground.

In either case, if it looks like that with a fresh battery supplying power, I would guess a $15-$20 multimeter is not economically repairable.